# intellij-internal error-buil error in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, error-handling, compiler-errors

Internal error (java.io.IOException): Cannot find IntelliJ IDEA project files at C:\Users\HUAWEI\IdeaProjects\lastone
java.io.IOException: Cannot find IntelliJ IDEA project files at C:\Users\HUAWEI\IdeaProjects\lastone
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:121)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:98)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:23)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:35)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:67)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:363)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:212)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:211)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)

how can ı solve this in intellij windows 10

Comment: Delete `.idea` directory in the project root, re-import the project, rebuild.

Comment: Did you read what the error says? Did you do what is suggested by the error message?